# three.js - Is there any way to import files from 3d studios?

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

My question is,can I import files (shapes) from 3d studios into three.js...
type of json or something? any types (*.obj...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They provide exporters for some software apps..

You can find an exporter from 3D studio max to three.js json format at https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/utils/exporters/max

Their Loaders can be found at https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/src/extras/loaders